# Check if a work profile is active on Android via ADB?

Tags: android, adb, smartphone

Can somebody tell me if there is any ADB command that could tell me if the freshly connected Android smartphone to the PC has the work profile enabled or not?

Visually (as a human) I can tell very quickly if the smartphone has a work profile or not, but how can I get this information via ADB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The work profile appears in the output of `pm list users`:

```
>.\adb.exe shell pm list users
Users:
        UserInfo{0:Keith Buck:13} running
        UserInfo{10:Workspace:10100030} running
```

In this case, user ID 10 is the work profile (I suspect it's always named "Workspace"). If the work profile is currently disabled, it won't show "running":

```
>.\adb.exe shell pm list users
Users:
        UserInfo{0:Keith Buck:13} running
        UserInfo{10:Workspace:101000b0}
```